# Model returns low training F1 Score, but high Testing and Validation F1 score

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, overfitting

I am currently working on a very imbalanced dataset:

- 24 million transactions (rows of data)
- 30,000 fraudulent transactions
  (0.1% of total transactions)

and I am using XGBoost as the model to predict whether a transaction is fraudulent or not. After tuning some hyperparameters via optuna, I have received such results

F1 Score on Training Data : 0.57417479049085 
F1 Score on Testing Data : 0.8719438392641008 
PR AUC score on Training Data : 0.9918559271777408 
PR AUC score on Testing Data : 0.9077624174590952

```
Training report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00  20579668
           1       0.47      1.00      0.64     25179

    accuracy                           1.00  20604847
   macro avg       0.73      1.00      0.82  20604847
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00  20604847

Test report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00   2058351
           1       0.83      0.93      0.87      2087

    accuracy                           1.00   2060438
   macro avg       0.91      0.96      0.94   2060438
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00   2060438
```

The following is my loss, learning curves and classification matrix 
**Loss data validation_0 is the trainingset, validation_1 is the testing set**

```
[0] validation_0-aucpr:0.75831  validation_0-logloss:0.67418    validation_1-aucpr:0.17989  validation_1-logloss:0.67417
[10]    validation_0-aucpr:0.78157  validation_0-logloss:0.52305    validation_1-aucpr:0.42574  validation_1-logloss:0.51965
[20]    validation_0-aucpr:0.83228  validation_0-logloss:0.41181    validation_1-aucpr:0.79299  validation_1-logloss:0.40593
[30]    validation_0-aucpr:0.84335  validation_0-logloss:0.32956    validation_1-aucpr:0.82845  validation_1-logloss:0.32171
[40]    validation_0-aucpr:0.86026  validation_0-logloss:0.26683    validation_1-aucpr:0.86401  validation_1-logloss:0.25788
[50]    validation_0-aucpr:0.87519  validation_0-logloss:0.21770    validation_1-aucpr:0.86298  validation_1-logloss:0.20919
[60]    validation_0-aucpr:0.88714  validation_0-logloss:0.17906    validation_1-aucpr:0.86130  validation_1-logloss:0.17034
[70]    validation_0-aucpr:0.89531  validation_0-logloss:0.14839    validation_1-aucpr:0.86285  validation_1-logloss:0.14016
[80]    validation_0-aucpr:0.89770  validation_0-logloss:0.12463    validation_1-aucpr:0.86329  validation_1-logloss:0.11545
[90]    validation_0-aucpr:0.90004  validation_0-logloss:0.10519    validation_1-aucpr:0.86052  validation_1-logloss:0.09647
[100]   validation_0-aucpr:0.90534  validation_0-logloss:0.08897    validation_1-aucpr:0.87044  validation_1-logloss:0.07986
[110]   validation_0-aucpr:0.91044  validation_0-logloss:0.07617    validation_1-aucpr:0.86994  validation_1-logloss:0.06662
[120]   validation_0-aucpr:0.91458  validation_0-logloss:0.06538    validation_1-aucpr:0.86962  validation_1-logloss:0.05589
[130]   validation_0-aucpr:0.91902  validation_0-logloss:0.05645    validation_1-aucpr:0.87092  validation_1-logloss:0.04684
[140]   validation_0-aucpr:0.92276  validation_0-logloss:0.04895    validation_1-aucpr:0.87258  validation_1-logloss:0.03967
[150]   validation_0-aucpr:0.92713  validation_0-logloss:0.04308    validation_1-aucpr:0.87285  validation_1-logloss:0.03377
[160]   validation_0-aucpr:0.93179  validation_0-logloss:0.03788    validation_1-aucpr:0.87703  validation_1-logloss:0.02851
[170]   validation_0-aucpr:0.93487  validation_0-logloss:0.03361    validation_1-aucpr:0.87967  validation_1-logloss:0.02426
[180]   validation_0-aucpr:0.93875  validation_0-logloss:0.03013    validation_1-aucpr:0.88027  validation_1-logloss:0.02093
[190]   validation_0-aucpr:0.94333  validation_0-logloss:0.02688    validation_1-aucpr:0.88284  validation_1-logloss:0.01781
[200]   validation_0-aucpr:0.94592  validation_0-logloss:0.02454    validation_1-aucpr:0.88497  validation_1-logloss:0.01577
[210]   validation_0-aucpr:0.95043  validation_0-logloss:0.02236    validation_1-aucpr:0.89025  validation_1-logloss:0.01363
[220]   validation_0-aucpr:0.95464  validation_0-logloss:0.02033    validation_1-aucpr:0.89146  validation_1-logloss:0.01172
[230]   validation_0-aucpr:0.95761  validation_0-logloss:0.01880    validation_1-aucpr:0.89327  validation_1-logloss:0.01044
[240]   validation_0-aucpr:0.96080  validation_0-logloss:0.01747    validation_1-aucpr:0.89531  validation_1-logloss:0.00912
[250]   validation_0-aucpr:0.96417  validation_0-logloss:0.01625    validation_1-aucpr:0.89891  validation_1-logloss:0.00802
[260]   validation_0-aucpr:0.96675  validation_0-logloss:0.01519    validation_1-aucpr:0.90279  validation_1-logloss:0.00712
[270]   validation_0-aucpr:0.96898  validation_0-logloss:0.01434    validation_1-aucpr:0.90530  validation_1-logloss:0.00645
[280]   validation_0-aucpr:0.97143  validation_0-logloss:0.01353    validation_1-aucpr:0.90629  validation_1-logloss:0.00573
[290]   validation_0-aucpr:0.97334  validation_0-logloss:0.01284    validation_1-aucpr:0.90836  validation_1-logloss:0.00520
[300]   validation_0-aucpr:0.97506  validation_0-logloss:0.01216    validation_1-aucpr:0.90954  validation_1-logloss:0.00468
[310]   validation_0-aucpr:0.97660  validation_0-logloss:0.01161    validation_1-aucpr:0.91150  validation_1-logloss:0.00427
[320]   validation_0-aucpr:0.97800  validation_0-logloss:0.01108    validation_1-aucpr:0.91411  validation_1-logloss:0.00386
[330]   validation_0-aucpr:0.97927  validation_0-logloss:0.01068    validation_1-aucpr:0.91551  validation_1-logloss:0.00361
[340]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98054  validation_0-logloss:0.01019    validation_1-aucpr:0.91600  validation_1-logloss:0.00323
[350]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98177  validation_0-logloss:0.00977    validation_1-aucpr:0.91776  validation_1-logloss:0.00299
[360]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98272  validation_0-logloss:0.00938    validation_1-aucpr:0.92028  validation_1-logloss:0.00275
[370]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98370  validation_0-logloss:0.00903    validation_1-aucpr:0.92015  validation_1-logloss:0.00256
[380]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98444  validation_0-logloss:0.00877    validation_1-aucpr:0.92196  validation_1-logloss:0.00242
[390]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98514  validation_0-logloss:0.00851    validation_1-aucpr:0.92389  validation_1-logloss:0.00229
[400]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98580  validation_0-logloss:0.00828    validation_1-aucpr:0.92348  validation_1-logloss:0.00219
[410]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98643  validation_0-logloss:0.00801    validation_1-aucpr:0.92514  validation_1-logloss:0.00203
[420]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98711  validation_0-logloss:0.00774    validation_1-aucpr:0.92575  validation_1-logloss:0.00189
[430]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98774  validation_0-logloss:0.00750    validation_1-aucpr:0.92427  validation_1-logloss:0.00177
[440]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98832  validation_0-logloss:0.00725    validation_1-aucpr:0.92531  validation_1-logloss:0.00164
[450]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98887  validation_0-logloss:0.00708    validation_1-aucpr:0.92623  validation_1-logloss:0.00160
[460]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98931  validation_0-logloss:0.00690    validation_1-aucpr:0.92806  validation_1-logloss:0.00151
[470]   validation_0-aucpr:0.98963  validation_0-logloss:0.00674    validation_1-aucpr:0.92860  validation_1-logloss:0.00146
[480]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99005  validation_0-logloss:0.00656    validation_1-aucpr:0.92980  validation_1-logloss:0.00140
[490]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99038  validation_0-logloss:0.00642    validation_1-aucpr:0.93051  validation_1-logloss:0.00135
[500]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99077  validation_0-logloss:0.00628    validation_1-aucpr:0.93089  validation_1-logloss:0.00131
[510]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99108  validation_0-logloss:0.00613    validation_1-aucpr:0.93270  validation_1-logloss:0.00126
[520]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99138  validation_0-logloss:0.00601    validation_1-aucpr:0.93254  validation_1-logloss:0.00122
[530]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99166  validation_0-logloss:0.00590    validation_1-aucpr:0.93199  validation_1-logloss:0.00119
[540]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99197  validation_0-logloss:0.00577    validation_1-aucpr:0.93318  validation_1-logloss:0.00116
[550]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99224  validation_0-logloss:0.00566    validation_1-aucpr:0.93408  validation_1-logloss:0.00112
[560]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99250  validation_0-logloss:0.00554    validation_1-aucpr:0.93327  validation_1-logloss:0.00109
[570]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99278  validation_0-logloss:0.00542    validation_1-aucpr:0.93397  validation_1-logloss:0.00106
[580]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99300  validation_0-logloss:0.00530    validation_1-aucpr:0.93339  validation_1-logloss:0.00102
[590]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99324  validation_0-logloss:0.00521    validation_1-aucpr:0.93372  validation_1-logloss:0.00100
[599]   validation_0-aucpr:0.99338  validation_0-logloss:0.00513    validation_1-aucpr:0.93378  validation_1-logloss:0.00099
```

**Confusion matrices of the trainig and testing sets**

[image: Training confusion matrix]

[image: Testing confusion matrix]

**Learning curve**

[image: Learning curve]

Although the PR AUC score are quite high, the F1 score of my trainig data is quite low and its PR AUC score is abnormally high.When intrepreting the loss and the learning curve, I see that the model is learning and generalizing well on the two sets (Although I have only included the testing sets here, results on the validation sets perform similarly). Is it safe to assume that my model is not overfitting, or is there something wrong with my intrepretation? I understand that overfitting means the data performs well on the training data, but can not generalize well into unseen data, and underfitting means that the model is unable to learn patterns from the training data, and their predictions suffer, but in this situation, it seems that my model is performing badly on the training data, but performs quite well on the testing sets. If it is not overfitting, what is wrong with my data, or my model, or are these results acceptable?

Comment: Looking at your confusion matrices, the test data seems to have many fewer true $1$s than the training data, which may affect some measures of quality. Another surprise is that your model seems deal with test data true $0$s better than training data   true $0$s (i.e. higher specificity) and that may point to the test and training data being different in some way; that test data shows lower sensitivity on the true $1$s is less surprising.

Comment: Is there some kind of artificial balancing in the training data?

Comment: @Henry the training and testing set were split by the feature "Year" on the same dataset,  I trained the model with the data before 2018, validated them on data in 2018 and tested them on data after 2018

Comment: @Dave Besides splitting the data, I did not modify the training data in any way, although I treated the imbalance of class distribution by setting a custom weight to the minority class